# How do I get the content of a xaml <Run> in .cs?

Tags: c#, wpf

`<Run>` does not contain properties like "Text" or "Content" alike many text XAML elements. I was trying to get the content of the `<Run>` element using

```
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(output.Inlines.ElementAt(0)));
```

Before that, I filled `output` which is a text block with `<Run>` elements, and this is why I used `ElementAt(0)`. However, the output that I get by running this code is "System.Windows.Documents.Run" instead of the value of the `<Run>` element. So how do I get the value of that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only Run in the collection, then you can do this:

```
 MessageBox.Show(((Run)output.Inlines.ElementAt(0)).Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you didn't get the output of the Text because you didn't cast it to Run.

After it's casted you can get the .Text property:

**XAML**

```
 <TextBlock Name="Text">
            <Run  Text="Hello"
                  FontSize="100"
                  Name="MyRun" />
    </TextBlock>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
MessageBox.Show(((Run)Text.Inlines.ElementAt(0)).Text);
```

**If you want to loop through multiple Runs:**

**XAML**

```
    <TextBlock Name="Text">
            <Run  Text="Hello"
                  FontSize="100"
                  Name="MyRun" />
        <Run  Text="My"
              FontSize="100"
              Name="MyRun2" />
        <Run  Text="Friend"
              FontSize="100"
              Name="MyRun3" />
    </TextBlock>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
for(int x = 0; x < Text.Inlines.Count; x++)
{
   MessageBox.Show(((Run)Text.Inlines.ElementAt(x)).Text);
}
```

Hope this helped.